# Why does HashSet.removeAll take a quadratic amount of operations?

Tags: java, collections

I have this code that generates a `HashSet` and calls `removeAll()` on it. I made a class `A` which is just a wrapper of an int, which records the number of times `equals` is called - the program outputs that number.

```
import java.util.*;

class A {
    int x;
    static int equalsCalls;

    A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        equalsCalls++;
        if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;
        return x == ((A)o).x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int setSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int listSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        Set<A> s = new HashSet<A>();
        for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i ++)
            s.add(new A(i));
        List<A> l = new LinkedList<A>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            l.add(new A(i));
        s.removeAll(l);
        System.out.println(A.equalsCalls);
    }
}
```

It turns out that the `removeAll` operation is not linear as I would have expected:

```
$ java A 10 10
55
$ java A 100 100
5050
$ java A 1000 1000
500500
```

In fact, it seems to be quadratic. Why?

Replacing the line `s.removeAll(l);` with `for (A b : l) s.remove(b);` fixes it to act the way I'd expect:

```
$ java A 10 10
10
$ java A 100 100
100
$ java A 1000 1000
1000
```

Why?

Here's a graph showing the quadratic curve:

[image]

The x and y axes are the two arguments to the Java program. The z axis is the number of `A.equals` calls.

---

The graph was generated by this [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) program:

```
import graph3;
import grid3;
import palette;

currentprojection=orthographic(0.8,1,1);

size(400,300,IgnoreAspect);

defaultrender.merge=true;

real[][] a = new real[][]{
  new real[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  new real[]{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  new real[]{0,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
  new real[]{0,1,2,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,78,78,78,78,78,78,78,78,78},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,91,91,91,91,91,91,91,91},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,105,105,105,105,105,105,105},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,120,120,120,120,120,120},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,136,136,136,136,136},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,153,153,153,153},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,171,171,171},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,190,190},
  new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,210},
};


surface s=surface(a,(-1/2,-1/2),(1/2,1/2),Spline);
draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black);
//grid3(XYZgrid);
```

The array `a` was generated by this Haskell program:

```
import System.Process
import Data.List

f :: Integer -> Integer -> IO Integer
f x y = fmap read $ readProcess "/usr/bin/java" ["A", show x, show y] ""

g :: [[Integer]] -> [String]
g xss = map (\xs -> "new real[]{" ++ intercalate "," (map show xs) ++ "},") xss

main = do
  let n = 20
  xs <- mapM (\x -> mapM (\y -> f x y) [0..n]) [0..n]
  putStrLn $ unlines $ g xs
```

Comment: Try running your program with `10 9`, `100 99` and `1000 999` for an even bigger surprise :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The time it takes for `removeAll` to work depends on what kind of collection you pass. When you look at the implementation of `removeAll`:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;

    if (size() > c.size()) {
        for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            modified |= remove(i.next());
    } else {
        for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

one can see that when the `HashSet` and the collection have the same size, it iterates over the `HashSet` and calls `c.contains` for each element. Since you are using a `LinkedList` as the argument, this is an O(n) operation for each element. Since it needs to do this for each of the n elements being removed, the result is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

If you replace the `LinkedList` with a collection that offers a more efficient implementation of `contains`, then the performance of `removeAll` should improve accordingly. If you make the `HashSet` larger than the collection, performance should also improve dramatically, since it will then iterate over the collection.

Comment: Why is `removeAll` doing all this? I thought `s.removeAll(c)` was just shorthand for `for (T x : c) s.remove(x);`. Is this documented or implementation dependent?

Comment: @Dog - It's not documented, so I'm sure it is implementation dependent. My guess is that checking the relative sizes of the collections is a heuristic that works well under the assumption that the two collections (the argument and `this`) have similar complexity for `contains`. The heuristic makes a lot of sense when the two collections have very different sizes. Your test happens to use a collection type that violates both the assumption and the conditions for the heuristic to be useful.

Comment: Actually, I think it might be specified behavior. In the HashSet API docs, it has `removeAll` in "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractSet", and in `AbstractSet`, it says what you said. Does the "Methods inherited from class" count as part of the spec? Or was that automatically generated from the code of an implementation?

Comment: @Dog - Wow. I never noticed that this was actually documented behavior. It certainly seems to be part of the specification for how `AbstractSet` behaves and, since `HashSet` does not override that method, it inherits the requirement to behave like that. However, the documentation starts with "_This_ implementation determines..." (emphasis added), so I'll leave it to the more legally minded to decide whether this is part of the specification of the method or a (non-binding) side comment. I think this was written before there was an awareness of how important the exact wording of the spec is.

Comment: @TedHopp the _specification_ for `removeAll()` is given by the `Set` interface, and is just "Removes from this set all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection".  The comment on `AbstractSet` then explains how that specification is implemented by this particular class.

Comment: @IanRoberts - Well, it's a matter of debate whether it's a comment or an extension of the spec. A similar problem occurs in `String.hashCode()`: the "spec" is given by `Object.hashCode()`, but `String.hashCode()` specifies _how_ the hash code is computed for `String` objects. This is generally considered as an extension of the spec; people have relied on being able to reproduce the hash code value of a string in their own code. It's also widely considered to have been a mistake to document the internal operation of `String.hashCode()` that way, but it's too late to do anything about it now.